# Invertibility of the Cartan matrix in the quiver representation theory

Tags: representation-theory, quiver

I have a question for Cartan matrix.

In the quiver representation theory, the Cartan matrix is defined as follows:

Let $Q$ be a quiver of type $A_n$ without oriented cycles 
Let $c_{ij}$ be the number of paths from $j$ to $i$. The matrix $C=(c_{ij})$ is called the Cartan matrix.

In my book[Ralf Schiffler, Quiver Representations, Springer] at page 74, the author has proved that $C$ is invetible by saying as follows:

Since $Q$ has no oriented cycles, we can renumber vertices to be $i\le j$ if there is a path from $j$ to $i$ in $Q$. Then the revised matrix is upper triangular with all diagonals 1, so $C$ is inveritible.

I have a question at this point. If we renumber our quiver $Q$, then the quiver is changed, so that we may get a new quiver. So, of course, the corresponding Cartan matrix of the new quiver is invertible upper triangular, but I cannot check whether the relation between the old and new ones is or not. More precisely, if the new Cartan matrix is invertible, then so is the old Cartan matrix, why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The quiver is the same, you have just relabelled the nodes. Another way to think about it is to order the columns/rows of $C$ so that the column/row labelled by row $i$ is to the left of column/row $j$ if $j\to i$.

Comment: Well, could you give me an example? In the book, the quiver 1 <- 2 <- 3 -> 4 <- 5 is given. If 3 and 4 are swapped, the corresponding matrix is upper triangular, but at the same time, the quiver is changed!

Comment: 1<-2<-4->3<-5 is the same quiver.

Comment: In the old one, there is an arrow from 3 to 2, but is not in the new one.

Comment: It's the same quiver. If I call the nodes blue, yellow, green, purple, and red, it's still the same quiver.

Comment: I know that the definition of a quiver is such that it has a set of vertices, a set of arrows, a starting point function, and an end point function. You say the sets of vertices are the same, but I think it's OK but the sets of arrows are different.

Comment: Let me rephrase what David Hill is saying.  The two quivers are isomorphic (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiver_(mathematics)#Definition) for the definition).  Try to prove the following lemma: *If two quivers are isomorphic, then their Cartan matrix have the same determinant*.  Hint: the two Cartan matrices are related by permuting rows and columns.